# React prevent our code from setting state if the component has been unmounted

Tags: reactjs

I have this on the useEffect, I receive that error:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a `useEffect` cleanup function.

```
useEffect(() => { top_10_articles(); ventas_mes_actual(); }, [])
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the two functions inside the useEffect?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give you some clues but better provide the code for the two functions. I guess they are either asynchronous or depend on external source. You may need to add a cleanup function. Refer to this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#explanation-why-effects-run-on-each-update).

```
useEffect(() => { 
    top_10_articles(); 
    ventas_mes_actual();  
    return function cleanup() {
       ..... undo the setters for example, depending on the above functions
    };
}, [])
```